# Can't switch between classic theme and fullscreen theme

Tags: jquery, galleria

I have decided to use the galleria jquery plugin for my portfolio site.
The way I want to implement it is with the classic theme on load.
Also, I have extended the classic theme with a button on the top left corner, when pushed the browser goes into fullscreen mode and galleria switches to the fullscreen theme.
In the fullscreen theme the same button is present, but when pushed again it switches back from fullscreen mode to normal and also back to the classic theme showing the rest of my site.

I can't seem to find a solution working satisfyingly.
What I have so far gets me into fullscreen and changes theme perfectly, but when I push the button again it goes back to the page and switches to classic with a fatal error stage height. I have tried to put the configure options many places, but i doesn't seem to run after loadtheme.

This is the code I'm stuck with so far:

```
    var OptionsFullscreen = {
    height: 1, //0.5625 16:9, 0.74 4:3 format
    imageCrop: false,
    idleSpeed: 100,
    idleTime: 1000,
    clicknext: true,
    transition: 'fade'
    };

var OptionsNormal = {
    height: 0.5625, //0.5625 16:9, 0.74 4:3 format
    imageCrop: false,
    idleSpeed: 100,
    idleTime: 1000,
    clicknext: true,
    transition: 'fade'
    };



Galleria.loadTheme('js/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.configure(OptionsNormal);

Galleria.run('#gallery', {
    extend: function() {

    var gallery = this;

    // Add button for toggling fullscreen theme
    this.addElement('fscr');
    this.appendChild('stage','fscr');

    var fscr = this.$('fscr')
    .text('Fullscreen')
    .click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault;

    gallery.toggleFullscreen();

    });

    this.addIdleState(this.get('fscr'), { opacity:0 });
    }
});



Galleria.ready(function() {



this.bind('fullscreen_enter', function() {
Galleria.loadTheme('js/themes/fullscreen/galleria.fullscreen.min.js');
});


this.bind('fullscreen_exit', function() {
Galleria.loadTheme('js/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.configure(OptionsNormal);
});

});
```